# gcloud project owner permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam, gcp-ai-platform-training

So I'm trying to run a training job on google cloud's AI-platform for an image classifier written in tensorflow by the command line:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training my_job \
          --module-name trainer.final_task \
          --staging-bucket gs://project_bucket \
          --package-path trainer/ \
```

but I keep getting the ERROR: `(gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.training) User [myemail@gmail.com] does not have permission to access project [my_project] (or it may not exist): Permission denied on 'locations/value' (or it may not exist).`

I don't get how this is possible as I own the project on gcloud (with that e-mail address) and am even expressly linked to it on the IAM policy bindings. Has anyone experienced this before?

**EXTRA INFO:**

- I am using gcloud as an individual, there are no organisations involved. Hence the only members linked in IAM policy bindings are me and gcloud service accounts.
- The code works perfectly when trained locally (using `gcloud ai-platform local train`) with the same parameters.

Comment: Are you in an organisation with some policies applied? Are you aware about this?

Comment: I am using gcloud as an individual, no organisations attached

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, having an owner account have permissions denied for training a job. I had accidentally added "central1" as the server when it had to be "us-central1". Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I need little more information to be sure, but such error appears when you have different project set in Gcloud SDK. Please verify if project in `gcloud config list project` is the same as the project you want to use. If not please submit `gcloud config set project [YOUR PROJECT]`. You can verify the changes with `list` command again.

Comment: The project is set to the one i would like to use, `gcloud config list project` reflects this as well

Comment: Do you know what is this path `locations/value`? Have you used your own code or used some repo?

Comment: I use the main script `final_task` that calls a few other scripts, all of my own code. However, none of these are called `value` or are located in a folder `locations`. There does appear to be a folder called `locations` in the main google cloud sdk installation folder. No `value` file though, and this is a fresh installation.

Comment: It will be hard without the code, however, the error says `Permission denied on 'locations/value' (or it may not exist)` so it seems that you are referring to not existing file or path. If I were in your shoes I would search for it in the code

Comment: I don't refer to it anywhere in my code. The code itself also works when i train it locally, but returns the error as soon as I try to submit it as a job on gcloud.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with me was that my notebook location was in a different region and I was trying to deploy in a different region. After I changed the location to my notebook location, it worked.